# Error while generating QR Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, qr-code

Currently I'm working on ASP.NET project where it's required to generate QR code with embedded  link.I'm getting this error :-

```
    A generic error occurred in GDI+.
```

Code that I used :-

```
    Bitmap img = encoder.Encode("http://localhost)/GFile/%20" + lblId.Text);
    img.Save("~/QRimage/" + txtFName.Text + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    QRImage.ImageUrl = txtFName.Text + ".jpg";
```

Stack trace:-

```
    [ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+.]
    System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder,  
    EncoderParameters encoderParams) +461268
    System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format) +69
    ViewResume.btnQRcode_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in   
    c:\Users\Samba\Desktop\Den\ViewResume.aspx.cs:341
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.
    RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
    System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String 
    eventArgument) +13
    System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint,   
    Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563
```

Comment: Hi, I have checked the other solution but still stuck. Hope someone can guide me as I didn't post this question without checking.

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong parentheses
change this:

`Bitmap img = encoder.Encode("http://localhost)/GFile/%20" + lblId.Text`);

to this:

```
Bitmap img = encoder.Encode("http://localhost/GFile/%20" + lblId.Text);
```

Comment: Hi,the error is showing at img.save, no problem with encoder part.

Comment: @NOORMOHAMED That is a possibility, if your img bitmap links to the wrong path, the save function generates an error because it cannot find the path you described. Have you tried changing it to the way I described?

Comment: I have tried change the path, but still having same problem.

Comment: Do you have the correct rights to save the img? What is the value of `txtFName.Text`

Comment: Yes,txtFName.Text just for name purpose of the image. Based on the answer that available, stated it's related to the file permission. But I still have no idea.